# How to dereference a dynamic multiple level pointer?

Tags: go

I was trying to implement a function to print the structure tree of an `interface{}` with reflection and DFS.

But I find it's hard to get dereference of a multiple level pointer (`NumField()`can not be used with a pointer). Just like:

```golang
func Tree(i interface{}) {
  ......
}

var a = 10
var b = &a
var c = &b

Tree(c)
```

In my opinion, maybe:

```golang
for reflect.ValueOf(i).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    t := i.(reflect.Typeof(i))
    i = *t
}
```

could work, but it doesn't.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: One of the go proverbs: [`interface{} says nothing`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=7m36s) it's worth watching those 5 minutes of the video.

Comment: Are you trying to print a tree of values or a tree of the types?  To put this another way, are you attempting to call [Value.NumField](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.NumField) or [Type.NumField](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.NumField)?

Comment: If you've got arbitrarily deep pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to... then I would strongly suggest rethinking your design rather than trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @Adrian I've just occasionally found there were ways to define a multiple levels pointer in golang. I shouldn't have known about that(maybe nobody codes like that, I still have to cover it), it could make my life easier.

Comment: Two levels (pointer to pointer to value) isn't unheard of, but it's pretty rare. I've never seen anyone use indirection deeper than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using reflection you can do this:

```
rt := reflect.ValueOf(i).Type()
for rt.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    rt = rt.Elem()
}

// rt is non-pointer type
```

https://play.golang.com/p/YbT1p4R3_1u

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to indirect through values:

```
 v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
 for v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !v.IsNil() {
    v = v.Elem()
 }
 // v.Interface() is nil pointer or non-pointer
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4fBTWIUA4FV)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `reflect.Indirect(interface{})`,

```golang
// Indirect returns the value that v points to.
// If v is a nil pointer, Indirect returns a zero Value.
// If v is not a pointer, Indirect returns v.
rv := reflect.Indirect(v)
```